# How to dynamically load a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I've two controller ensted:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="init({role='widget1'})">   
    <div ng-controller="ctrlToLoad" ng-init="init({action='put'})" ng-include="aVariable">
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ctrlToLoad" ng-init="init({action='delete'})" ng-include="aVariable">
    </div>
</div>
```

The aim is to dynamically load a template into the second div with a certain controller, depending of parameters managed by my mainController like:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $sce, ...) {
    if(/*Something*/){
        $scope.ctrlToLoad = 'anOtherController'
    }
});
myApp.controller('anOtherController', function($scope, $sce, ...) {
    // Some jobs...
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at ui router? If you change your perspective a bit, it does pretty much what you want to achieve here.

Comment: If you define the controller at the template level then, you don't have to do what you are doing. Declare the controller on template html.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand I already use `ng-view` to switch from a layout to another. Can I use embeded `ng-view`?

Comment: @Chandermani Mmh, I see, but can I also pass my option like ng-init? Can I do something like `ng-include=aFunction({action='delete'})`?

Comment: The controller can define these init properties itself. Or else ng-init can be used to pass some value. Also remember the parent scope properties would by default be available for all you child\template views.